# Group Array of Objects based on combination of Year and Month

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, frontend

i Have an Array of Objects Like this:

The array is sorted based on the date:

```js
//My Actual React Context Dates are built with Date() and like this: Fri Apr 16 2021 13:22:24 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time)
  
  const transactions =  [
    {
        "amount": 42,
        "text": "",
        "date": "2021-04-16T08:52:24.408Z",
        "type": "Expense",
        "category": "Car",
        "id": "dda58c24-92fc-431f-a4eb-d89fad5cdf81"
    },
    {
        "amount": 3000,
        "text": "",
        "date": "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z",
        "type": "Income",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "915db4d8-1b20-4455-be06-c50b15920ae8"
    },
    {
        "amount": 2997,
        "text": "",
        "date": "2021-03-17T20:30:00.000Z",
        "type": "Income",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "ec1608b1-dc4f-428d-9d41-006322b2cf78"
    },
   
    {
        "amount": 19993,
        "text": "",
        "date": "2021-02-01T20:30:00.000Z",
        "type": "Income",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "5f51a268-4d68-4407-87f2-3156d27d5084"
    },
    {
        "amount": 1000,
        "text": "",
        "date": "2021-01-06T20:30:00.000Z",
        "type": "Expense",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "554b0776-8fad-46da-9609-e617f33b4e0e"
    },
    {
        "amount": 96,
        "text": "",
        "date": "2020-08-06T19:30:00.000Z",
        "type": "Income",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "1b806abf-9012-477f-9f1b-c99c53e1cb7d"
    }]

  const formatedDate = transactions.map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      year: item.date.getFullYear(),
      month: item.date.getMonth(),
    };
  });
```

[image: Final Design]

I have two questions:

1. How can I group them by Year and month?
2. How can I map over sorted and grouped output and make my page?

I found out that if I group them as One Object because objects can not be sorted I can't iterate over them.

Comment: You could easily make a [mcve] and not tag it react. Please fix the code to run in a `[<>]` snippet

Comment: Working on a full solution to this now. I'll post soon.

Comment: @ASCode94 I've finished and posted my solution. Please take a look at the final solution as well to see all the logic and the code in action. It's exactly matched to the design your provided, with just an added fancy outline as a personal touch. Let me know what you think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright! So this is a bit of a two-part task. First we'll conquer the object reorganization into years and months and then work on the actual HTML output:

## 1. Building our new Object (vs. Array)

#### 1.1. As an Object

Here, I am converting the data you provided to an Object:

```js
const transactions = [
    { amount: 42, text: "", date: "2021-04-16T08:52:24.408Z", type: "Expense", category: "Car", id: "dda58c24-92fc-431f-a4eb-d89fad5cdf81" },
    { amount: 3000, text: "", date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "915db4d8-1b20-4455-be06-c50b15920ae8" },
    { amount: 2997, text: "", date: "2021-03-17T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "ec1608b1-dc4f-428d-9d41-006322b2cf78" },
    { amount: 19993, text: "", date: "2021-02-01T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "5f51a268-4d68-4407-87f2-3156d27d5084" },
    { amount: 1000, text: "", date: "2021-01-06T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Expense", category: "Salary", id: "554b0776-8fad-46da-9609-e617f33b4e0e" },
    { amount: 96, text: "", date: "2020-08-06T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "1b806abf-9012-477f-9f1b-c99c53e1cb7d" }
];

const organizedTransactions = Object.fromEntries([...new Set(transactions.map(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[0])))].map(yr => [yr, Object.fromEntries([...new Set(transactions.filter(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[0]) === yr).map(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[1])))].map(mo => [mo, transactions.filter(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[0]) === yr && parseInt(t.date.split('-')[1]) === mo)]))]));

console.log(organizedTransactions);
```

This works great for reorganizing our date by year and month, but it will actually create more work for us when trying to display the content in our HTML page. That's because JavaScript objects don't reliably respect their insertion order. We can organize the date ^this way but we'll need to convert it back to an array later when we want to sort it by year and month.

Instead, let's use a *slightly* different version of that same function to convert the data into a series of nested arrays and then sort that date in descending order (most recent first):

#### 1.2. As an Array

```js
const transactions = [
    { amount: 42, text: "", date: "2021-04-16T08:52:24.408Z", type: "Expense", category: "Car", id: "dda58c24-92fc-431f-a4eb-d89fad5cdf81" },
    { amount: 3000, text: "", date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "915db4d8-1b20-4455-be06-c50b15920ae8" },
    { amount: 2997, text: "", date: "2021-03-17T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "ec1608b1-dc4f-428d-9d41-006322b2cf78" },
    { amount: 19993, text: "", date: "2021-02-01T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "5f51a268-4d68-4407-87f2-3156d27d5084" },
    { amount: 1000, text: "", date: "2021-01-06T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Expense", category: "Salary", id: "554b0776-8fad-46da-9609-e617f33b4e0e" },
    { amount: 96, text: "", date: "2020-08-06T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "1b806abf-9012-477f-9f1b-c99c53e1cb7d" }
];

const organizedTransactions = [...new Set(transactions.map(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[0])))].map(yr => [yr, [...new Set(transactions.filter(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[0]) === yr).map(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[1])))].map(mo => [mo, transactions.filter(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[0]) === yr && parseInt(t.date.split('-')[1]) === mo).map(t => ({ ...t, sign: t.type === "Income" ? 1 : -1 }))]).sort((a,b) => b[0] - a[0])]).sort((a,b) => b[0] - a[0]);

console.log(organizedTransactions);
```

This will make our data much easier to iterate through sequentially, as it's now all in the correct order. I've also added an additional `sign` property to each transaction's object to quickly tell whether it is an `Income` or an `Expense` without having to evaluate the strings repeatedly later.

## 2. Building our App ✨

Now for building out our HTML and CSS… You can run the snippet below and maximize the size of the snippet preview to see a larger preview or visit this [CodePen preview](https://cdpn.io/e/4c2d148cf99e3d98c10f0d083bf29da1) to see it in action.

```js
const transactionsDiv = document.getElementById('transactions');

const transactionData = [
  { amount: 42, text: "", date: "2021-04-16T08:52:24.408Z", type: "Expense", category: "Car", id: "dda58c24-92fc-431f-a4eb-d89fad5cdf81" },
  { amount: 3000, text: "", date: "2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "915db4d8-1b20-4455-be06-c50b15920ae8" },
  { amount: 2997, text: "", date: "2021-03-17T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "ec1608b1-dc4f-428d-9d41-006322b2cf78" },
  { amount: 19993, text: "", date: "2021-02-01T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "5f51a268-4d68-4407-87f2-3156d27d5084" },
  { amount: 1000, text: "", date: "2021-01-06T20:30:00.000Z", type: "Expense", category: "Salary", id: "554b0776-8fad-46da-9609-e617f33b4e0e" },
  { amount: 96, text: "", date: "2020-08-06T19:30:00.000Z", type: "Income", category: "Salary", id: "1b806abf-9012-477f-9f1b-c99c53e1cb7d" }
];

const organizedTransactionData = [...new Set(transactionData.map(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[0])))].map(yr => [yr, [...new Set(transactionData.filter(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[0]) === yr).map(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[1])))].map(mo => [mo, transactionData.filter(t => parseInt(t.date.split('-')[0]) === yr && parseInt(t.date.split('-')[1]) === mo).map(t => ({ ...t, sign: t.type === "Income" ? 1 : -1 }))]).sort((a,b) => b[0] - a[0])]).sort((a,b) => b[0] - a[0]);

const leadZero = number => ('0'+number).slice(-2);

for (const [year, months] of organizedTransactionData) {
  const formatMonth = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' });
  for (const [month, transactions] of months) {
    transactionsDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<h2 id="transaction-group-heading-${year}-${leadZero(month)}" class="transaction-group-heading">${formatMonth.format(new Date(transactions[0].date))} ${year}</h2><div class="transaction-group" id="transactions-${year}-${leadZero(month)}"></div>`);
    const monthDiv = transactionsDiv.querySelector(`#transactions-${year}-${leadZero(month)}`);
    for (transaction of transactions) {
      const date = new Date(transaction.date);
      monthDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="transaction" tabindex="0" data-copy-content="${date.getMonth()+1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}, ${transaction.type}, ${transaction.category}, ${!!(transaction.sign+1) ? '+' : '-'}$${transaction.amount.toString().split('.').map((e,i) => i ? e : e.split('').reverse().map(((f,j) => j && j % 3 === 0 ? f + ',' : f)).reverse().join('')).join('.')}"><div class="transaction-overview"><div class="transaction-date">${date.getDate()}</div><div class="transaction-type-category"><div class="transaction-type">${transaction.type}</div><div class="transaction-category">${transaction.category}</div></div><div class="transaction-amount ${transaction.type.toLowerCase()}">${!!(transaction.sign+1) ? '+' : '-'}$${transaction.amount.toString().split('.').map((e,i) => i ? e : e.split('').reverse().map(((f,j) => j && j % 3 === 0 ? f + ',' : f)).reverse().join('')).join('.')}</div></div><div class="transaction-details"><strong class="transaction-id-label">Transaction ID</strong><span class="transaction-id">${Math.floor(Math.random()*10e20).toString().replace(/0/g, '').slice(0,10)}</span><strong class="merchant-label">Merchant</strong><span class="merchant">Lorem Bizpsum</span><strong class="datetime-label">Datetime</strong><span class="datetime">${year}-${leadZero(month)}-${leadZero(date.getDate())} ${leadZero(date.getHours())}:${leadZero(date.getMinutes())}:${leadZero(date.getSeconds())} GTM${Math.sign(-1 * date.getTimezoneOffset())+1 ? '+' : '-'}${Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset()) / 60}</span></div></div>`);
    }
  }
}

const transactions = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.transaction'));
const toggleFocus = transaction => (transactions.forEach(transaction => transaction.classList.remove('focused')), transaction.classList.toggle('focused'));
const applyFocus = transaction => (transactions.forEach(transaction => transaction.classList.remove('focused')), transaction.focus(), transaction.classList.add('focused'));
const removeFocus = transaction => transaction.classList.remove('focused');
const persistBlur = element => { element.blur(); element.focus(); element.blur(); };
document.addEventListener('focus', e => e.target?.matches('.transaction') && applyFocus(e.target));
document.addEventListener('focusout', e => e.target?.matches('.transaction') && removeFocus(e.target));
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target?.matches('.transaction')) {
        if (e.target.matches('.focused')) {
            persistBlur(e.target);
            removeFocus(e.target);
        } else { toggleFocus(e.target); }
    }
});

const copyToClipboard = str => {
    const el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.value = str;
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.left = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    const selected = document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0 ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) : false;
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(el);
    if (selected) {
        document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        document.getSelection().addRange(selected);
    }
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    const activeElement = document.activeElement;
    if (e.keyCode === 67 && e.metaKey && activeElement.matches('.transaction')) {
        copyToClipboard(activeElement.dataset.copyContent);
        applyFocus(activeElement);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    const activeElement = document.activeElement;
    if (e.keyCode === 9 && activeElement.matches('.transaction')) {
        applyFocus(activeElement);
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,500;1,500&family=Roboto+Mono&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
html {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
#transactions {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 16px 40px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#transactions::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 32px);
  border: 7px double #c69e3d;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#transactions-heading {
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 30px -10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  color: #c69e3d;
}
.transaction-group-heading {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #6e7c92;
}
.transaction-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.transaction-group + .transaction-group-heading {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.transaction {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
.transaction + .transaction {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.transaction:focus, .transaction.focused {
  background-color: #edf8ff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #2babff, 0 10px 20px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transform: scale(1.06);
  outline: 0 !important;
  z-index: 2;
}
.transaction + .transaction:focus,
.transaction + .transaction.focused,
.transaction:focus + .transaction,
.transaction.focused + .transaction {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.transaction-overview {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: inherit;
}
.transaction-overview, .transaction-details {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.transaction-date {
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #dde4ed;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.transaction-type-category {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  /* fallback for older browsers */
  gap: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.transaction-type-category > .transaction-type {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #282730;
}
.transaction-type-category > .transaction-category {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #939fb4;
}
.transaction-amount {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.transaction-amount.income {
  color: #319459;
}
.transaction-amount.expense {
  color: #d92a32;
}
.transaction-details {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  gap: 5px;
  padding-top: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: inherit;
}
.transaction:focus .transaction-details,
.transaction.focused .transaction-details {
  padding-top: 30px;
  max-height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.transaction-details strong {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #75849f;
}
.transaction-details span {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #282730;
}
.transaction-details .transaction-id {
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", consolas, courier, monospace;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6e7c92;
}
footer #copyright strong {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #282730;
}
footer #copyright a {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #c69e3d;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #c69e3d !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
footer #copyright a:focus {
  color: #fff !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
footer #copyright a:focus::before {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(43, 171, 255, 0.75);
}
footer #copyright a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -5px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  background-color: #c69e3d;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: inherit;
}
footer #social-icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
footer #social-icons a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #c69e3d;
  border-radius: 24px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer #social-icons a:focus {
  background-color: var(--brand-color);
  outline: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(43, 171, 255, 0.75);
}
footer #social-icons a + a {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
svg.spinner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  x: 0px;
  y: 0px;
  viewBox: 0 0 80 80;
  transition: all 0.5 ease-out;
  height: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
svg.spinner:last-child {
  height: 80px;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
svg.spinner circle {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #282730;
  stroke-width: 6;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 251.2;
  transform-origin: 40px 40px 0;
  -webkit-animation: spinner 4s linear infinite;
          animation: spinner 4s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 52.8;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 251.2;
    transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 52.8;
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 52.8;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 251.2;
    transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 52.8;
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 399px) {
  #transactions-heading {
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  #transactions::before {
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
  }
}
@media (hover: hover) {
  footer #copyright a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  footer #copyright a:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  footer #social-icons a:hover {
    background-color: var(--brand-color);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/07afc061fe.js"></script>
<div id="transactions"><h1 id="transactions-heading">My Transactions</h1><svg class="spinner"><circle cx="40" cy="40" r="36"></circle></svg></div>
<footer>
    <div id="copyright"><i class="fab fa-creative-commons"></i> Designed and developed by <strong>Brandon McConnell</strong> to answer StackOverflow question <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67124430/group-array-of-objects-based-on-combination-of-year-and-month" target="_blank">#67124430</a></div>
    <div id="social-icons">
        <a href="https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/" target="_blank" title="Brandon McConnell on CodePen" style="--brand-color: #000;">
            <i class="fab fa-codepen"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824249/brandon-mcconnell" target="_blank" title="Brandon McConnell on Stack Overflow" style="--brand-color: #f48024;">
            <i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/endpaperstraws" target="_blank" title="Brandon McConnell on Twitter" style="--brand-color: #1da1f2;">
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="https://github.com/brandonmcconnell" target="_blank" title="Brandon McConnell on GitHub" style="--brand-color: #6e5494;">
            <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Wow ! Brandon, Thank you so much that's exactly what i needed, you are awesome man .

Comment: @ASCode94 I'm glad it helped! I really enjoyed making it

Comment: @ASCode94 check out the new updated version^ I added hover and focus styles, expandable transaction details on focus (via tab or click), tabbable navigation between transactions, and the ability to copy transaction details using Ctrl/Cmd+C while a transaction is focused

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a `groupBy` helper.

```js
function groupBy(iterable, keyFn) {
  const groups = new Map();
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = keyFn(item);
    if (!groups.has(key)) groups.set(key, []);
    groups.get(key).push(item);
  }
  return groups;
}
```

Using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the groups has the advantage that it is iterable using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and has a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) method. If you want to use `.map()` (available on arrays) you can easily convert the map to an array using `Array.from(groupedTransactions)`.

Iteration is done based on insertion order, but since you say that the current array is ordered based on date you should be good to go.

Assuming your `date` properties are [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instances and not strings, like your comment says. You can then group your items using:

```js
const groupedTransactions = groupBy(transactions, ({ date }) => (
  JSON.stringify([date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()])
));
```

The reason to use `JSON.stringify([date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()])` and not `[date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()]` is because strings are compared based on content, while objects (including arrays) are compared by reference eg. `[] == [] //=> false` because they are two different arrays even though their content is the same (empty).

Here is an example without fancy formatting:

```js
function groupBy(iterable, keyFn) {
  const groups = new Map();
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = keyFn(item);
    if (!groups.has(key)) groups.set(key, []);
    groups.get(key).push(item);
  }
  return groups;
}

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat
const monthFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { month: "short", year: "numeric" });
const dayFormatter   = Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", { day: "2-digit" });
const amountSigns    = { Income: "+", Expense: "-" };

// assumes tranasctions are already sorted by date
function Transactions({ transactions }) {
  // use the useMemo hook to increase performance
  const groupedTransactions = groupBy(transactions, ({ date }) => (
    JSON.stringify([date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()])
  ));

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Transactions</h1>
      {Array.from(groupedTransactions).map(renderGroup)}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function renderGroup([key, transactions]) {
  const [year, month] = JSON.parse(key); // 0-based month
  return (
    <div key={key}>
      <h2>{monthFormatter.format(new Date(year, month))}</h2>
      <table>
        <tbody>{transactions.map(renderTransaction)}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

function renderTransaction(transaction) {
  return (
    <tr key={transaction.id}>
      <td>{dayFormatter.format(transaction.date)}</td>
      <td>{transaction.type}: {transaction.category}</td>
      <td className={transaction.type}>
        {amountSigns[transaction.type]}{transaction.amount}
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}

const transactions =  [
    {
        "amount": 42,
        "text": "",
        "date": new Date("2021-04-16T08:52:24.408Z"),
        "type": "Expense",
        "category": "Car",
        "id": "dda58c24-92fc-431f-a4eb-d89fad5cdf81"
    },
    {
        "amount": 3000,
        "text": "",
        "date": new Date("2021-04-14T19:30:00.000Z"),
        "type": "Income",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "915db4d8-1b20-4455-be06-c50b15920ae8"
    },
    {
        "amount": 2997,
        "text": "",
        "date": new Date("2021-03-17T20:30:00.000Z"),
        "type": "Income",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "ec1608b1-dc4f-428d-9d41-006322b2cf78"
    },
   
    {
        "amount": 19993,
        "text": "",
        "date": new Date("2021-02-01T20:30:00.000Z"),
        "type": "Income",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "5f51a268-4d68-4407-87f2-3156d27d5084"
    },
    {
        "amount": 1000,
        "text": "",
        "date": new Date("2021-01-06T20:30:00.000Z"),
        "type": "Expense",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "554b0776-8fad-46da-9609-e617f33b4e0e"
    },
    {
        "amount": 96,
        "text": "",
        "date": new Date("2020-08-06T19:30:00.000Z"),
        "type": "Income",
        "category": "Salary",
        "id": "1b806abf-9012-477f-9f1b-c99c53e1cb7d"
    }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Transactions transactions={transactions} />, document.querySelector("#transactions"));
```

```css
.Expense { color: red }
.Income { color: green }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="transactions"></div>
```